# How to Write Webtable data into xlsx using poi and selenium(java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can any one please help me  to fetch web table data into **XLSX** file using selenium and java.I am not able to find a solution...let me know if thr is a better way of doing it

My Code :

```
List<WebElement> rows=sectiontable.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); 
Iterator<WebElement> i=rows.iterator(); 

int x=0; 
while(i.hasNext())
{   
    WebElement row=i.next(); 
    List<WebElement> columns=row.findElements(By.tagName("td")); 
     Iterator<WebElement> j=columns.iterator(); int y=1; while(j.hasNext())        
       {         
     WebElement column=j.next(); this. s=column.getText();
  } System.out.println("x=" +"" +x);
            System.out.println("y=" +""+y);
            System.out.println(s);


            //y=y+1;
            if(y==1){
                this.c1= this. s;
                System.out.println(c1);
            }
            if(y==2){
                this.c2= this. s;
                System.out.println(c2);
            }
            if(y==3){
                this.c3= this. s;
                System.out.println(c3);
            }

        if(y==4){
            this.c4= this. s;
            System.out.println(c4);
        }
        if(y==5){
            this.c5= this. s;
            System.out.println(c5);
        }   int t=0;
        for(int u=1;u<this.tablerows;u++){
        HashMap<Integer, Object[]> data = new HashMap<Integer, Object[]>();
        //String str=Integer.toString(u);
        data.put(t++, new Object[] {t,this.c1, this.c2, this.c3,this.c4,this.c5});

        //data.put("1", new Object[] {"s1","s2"});
        //data.put("2", new Object[] {"s3","s4"});
         Set<Integer> keyset = data.keySet();
            int rownum = 0;
            for (Integer key : keyset)
            {
                Row row1 = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
                int cellnum = 0;
                for (Object obj : objArr)
                {
                    Cell cell=row1.createCell(cellnum++);
                   if(obj instanceof String)
                        cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                    else if(obj instanceof Integer)
                        cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
                   //Write the workbook in file system
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://demo1.xlsx"));
                    workbook.write(out);
                }
            }
        }
          y=y+1;
        }
    x=x+1;
}
        try
        {
            //Write the workbook in file system
          //  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("D://demo1.xlsx"));
            //workbook.write(out);


            //out.close();
            System.out.println("demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
This is the method for featching data from table that is being identified
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: [Google It](http://goo.gl/xX2TB8)

Comment: I have extracted the web table and tto pass it to hashMap.But every time the row is getting replaced with the new data being fetched....

Comment: Please share code which you have written.

Comment: List<WebElement> rows=sectiontable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
  Iterator<WebElement> i=rows.iterator();
  int x=0;
  while(i.hasNext()){
   WebElement row=i.next();
   List<WebElement> columns=row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
   Iterator<WebElement> j=columns.iterator();
   int y=1;
   while(j.hasNext())
   {
       WebElement column=j.next();
     this. s=column.getText();

Comment: I am unable to share my code in comments...so can you let me know the mail id to share it

Comment: Kindly share code by updating your question. See I have added this code , please you share whole code.

Comment: Hi I have attached my code...please kindly share your valuable suggestion.

Comment: What error you getting while run code?

Comment: The old data is being replaced by newly fetched data in the excel.So after execution of script only last row data of web table is only being written in excel

Comment: Because you are starting row each time rownum =0 , instead of this do like `rownum = sheet.getlastrownum()`.

Comment: I tried it but the result is same...

Comment: Do one this , create new variable for row count `rowcount= sheet.getLastRowNum();` , then do `Row row1 = sheet.createRow(rowcount++);`

Comment: Its behaving in the same way

Comment: `cellnum++` not require. Make it `cellnum` only

Comment: If cellnum is not incremented then its not writing any thing in the excel...

Comment: If you want to write data vertically then you need to increment only rownum. If you want to write data horizontally then you need to increment only cellnum. This is logic.

Comment: The proble with the current scritp is its replacing the old data....so only one row is being written every time(only the last row data is being saved)I want to write the entire table rows and columns data into excel